# Github Actions create secret from pipeline

Tags: github, devops, github-actions

I am creating Cloud Resources from Github actions using Terraform. To authenticate against the cloud provider I am using client secret stored as Github secret. Nevertheless I obtain connection strings from resources I created in the cloud as output from terraform and I need to store those as secret for use in further steps of the pipeline. Please any suggestion how to achieve that?

Comment: You can use a dedicated action like https://github.com/marketplace/actions/set-action-secret

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out, it is not necessary to create a secret, in my case. I ended up using add mask command which masks specified string across whole pipeline:

```
- name: Set env
  run: |
   x="randomstring"
   echo ::add-mask::$x
   echo $x

Output: ***
```